# MVC dropdownlist - conditional attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can someone tell me how to get the effect like in the picture? Maybe an example?

[image]

He wants the contents of the second list was dependent on the option selected from the first.

Answer (score 0):

Make ajax call on first drop down list change event and bind second drop down list